# How do I remove a particular option from a jQuery Select2 element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using jQuery Select2 (version 4).

I am using a select tag along with multiple selection allowed option.

I am able to clear selected options using

```
 selectTest.val(null).trigger('change');
```

[Working demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamjgalt/m1yadgzt/)

But unable to unselect only one of the value on a button click. help me.

- Priyank

Comment: What makes that option "particular"?

Comment: like there are 4 options (1, 2, 3 ,4 ). User has selected 1 and 2. Now I want to remove 1 from selection on button click. Button is provided by me.

Comment: Works perfectly good for me. I can click the already selected options and they are removed

Comment: What browser are you trying this in? it works for me too

Comment: @JamieHutber: Yes.. but if you want to remove only of them then?

Comment: He wants to remove an option _programmatically_. Get the selected options (_an array_), remove the option, and reset the value. It seems the library doesn't have  API for removing options.

Comment: @SameerAlibhai I have edited my question. Sorry I wasn't clear at first about explaining what I want

Comment: @Vohuman: please post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deselect an option programmatically you can select the target option and set it's `selected` property to `false`.

```
$('#btn-clear').on('click', function () {
    var value = '2';
    // find the target option
    // if you want to deselect more that 1 option
    // you can use an array and jQuery `$.inArray` methiod, i.e.:
    // return $.inArray(this.value, values) > -1;
    selectTest.children().filter(function() {
       return this.value == value;
    }).prop('selected', false);
    // trigger the change event so the library recreates the tags
    selectTest.change();
});
```

I have [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1yadgzt/1/).

Note that `if(selectTest){` is always `true`. jQuery constructor returns an object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript. You should check the `length` of the collection.

```
if ( selectTest.length > 0 )
//   ...
```